# Steam web api get items tag (TF2)

Tags: php, api, steam

I am trying to get the tags from some items but i cant find a function that give me these tags..
I am using `GetPlayerItems` from the steam web API to get the player items but it wont give me
the item tags, what should i do?

is there a way to give me the tags?

and i have another question,
is there a fast way to pull the image of the item? not by storing it on my server?
i mean like an URL to the image through steam server or something..

i have tried `GetSchema` to find information for an item but i dont really get how it works.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to combine two separate API calls to link the GetPlayerItems to what the data actually means.

Perform you `GetPlayerItems` call and return data. In the return data, you will iterate over `result['items']` to get a listing of the player items.

One item in that array may look like this:

```
{
            "id": 493336261,
            "original_id": 493336261,
            "defindex": 5050,
            "level": 50,
            "quality": 6,
            "inventory": 2147483948,
            "quantity": 1,
            "origin": 2,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "defindex": 195,
                    "value": 1065353216,
                    "float_value": 1.000000
                }
            ]

},
```

Using this data, you can use the `defindex` to look at the `result['items']` array returned from your `GetSchema` call. You will have to iterate through each of those items comparing the `GetPlayerItems` defindex to the `GetSchema` defindex. When it matches you have know what the item is.

In the above case, `5050` is a `Backpack Expander`. You can pull the image for this item by looking at the `image_url` or `image_url_large` values on the `GetSchema` match.

For the "tags" that you mention, I am assuming you mean `attributes`. These can be matched by following a similar process, but instead matching against the `GetSchema` `result['attributes']` array. Again, you'll have to loop through all and compare `defindex` values.

For the above example, the attribute with `defindex = 195` matches this:

```
        {
            "name": "always tradable",
            "defindex": 195,
            "attribute_class": "always_tradable",
            "description_string": "#Attrib_Always_Tradable",
            "description_format": "value_is_additive",
            "effect_type": "negative",
            "hidden": true,
            "stored_as_integer": false
        },
```

The `float_value` of `1.0` in the `GetPlayerItems` attributes indicates that this object has that attribute. So, this backpack expander is always tradable.

Comment: But if the item is made random i mean with powers and stuff (like fire etc..) how can i know that?
thanks!