# Steam Web API GetPlayerItems

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

How can I use the results of this query:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=KEY&SteamID=64ID
```

to understand the attributes of individual weapons in CS:GO.? The values I get for a players inventory look like this:

```
            "id": 2062813155,
            "original_id": 262087494,
            "defindex": 7,
            "level": 1,
            "quality": 4,
            "inventory": 93,
            "quantity": 1,
            "custom_name": "big blu",
            "rarity": 5,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "defindex": 6,
                    "value": 1110441984,
                    "float_value": 44
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 7,
                    "value": 1147016758,
                    "float_value": 888.3470458984375
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 8,
                    "value": 1039827197,
                    "float_value": 0.12231633812189102
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 111,
                    "value": "big blu"
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 147,
                    "value": "models/weapons/stattrack.mdl"
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 39,
                    "value": 0,
                    "float_value": 0.43999999761581421
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 40,
                    "value": 0,
                    "float_value": 0.10000000149011612
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 145,
                    "value": "models/weapons/w_rif_ak47_mag.mdl"
                }
```

Qualities like the first defindex and rarity are pretty straight forward. How or where can I find the meaning of the attribute defindexs. I know that defindex:8 attribute is wear value, what do the others mean or where can I find out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Steam web api get items tag (TF2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381591/steam-web-api-get-items-tag-tf2)

Comment: This is a duplicate of the above. The only difference is that you need to issue a GetSchema call to the CSGO application instead of TF2.